# How to change the iou in tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: api, object, tensorflow, detection

i cannot find the iou threshold to change it. Also what is the iou_threshold for second_stage_post_processing  and first_stage_nms_iou_threshold?

Comment: go to object_detection_evaluation.py in utils folder and change the matching_iou_threshold